# Flutter: How efficient is to store widget in variable?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I had this class ( below is logic )

```
class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        slivers: [
          SliverPersistentHeader(
            delegate: HeaderWithHorizontalList(),
            pinned: true,
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
              if (index > 30) return null;
              return Container(
                color: ColorHelper.primary.withOpacity(index / 30),
                height: SizeHelper.width(40),
              );
            }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And above class is using this stateless widget

**Old Code**

```
class HeaderWithHorizontalList extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {

  @override
  double get maxExtent => 284;

  @override
  double get minExtent => 106;

  @override
  Widget build(
    BuildContext context,
    double shrinkOffset,
    bool overlapsContent,
  ) {
    double visiblePixels = max(minExtent, maxExtent - shrinkOffset);
    double travelledPixels = maxExtent - visiblePixels;
    double percentage = travelledPixels / (maxExtent - minExtent);

    return Material(
      color: Colors.white,
      elevation: percentage * 8,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        overflow: Overflow.clip,
                children: AppHorizontalScroll(
                    verticalPadding: 19,
                    horizontalPadding: 22,
                    betweenPadding: 13,
                    items: [
                        MyCustomWidget(
                            type: MyCustomWidgetType.1,
                            isActive: false,
                        ),
                        MyCustomWidget(
                            type: MyCustomWidgetType.2,
                            isActive: false,
                        ),
                        MyCustomWidget(
                            type: MyCustomWidgetType.3,
                            isActive: false,
                        ),
                        MyCustomWidget(
                            type: MyCustomWidgetType.4,
                            isActive: false,
                        ),
                    ],
                ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

**New Code**

```
class HeaderWithHorizontalList extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  List<PreferredSizeWidget> list = [
    MyCustomWidget(
      type: MyCustomWidgetType.1,
      isActive: false,
    ),
    MyCustomWidget(
      type: MyCustomWidgetType.2,
      isActive: false,
    ),
    MyCustomWidget(
      type: MyCustomWidgetType.3,
      isActive: false,
    ),
    MyCustomWidget(
      type: MyCustomWidgetType.4,
      isActive: false,
    ),
  ];

  @override
  double get maxExtent => 284;

  @override
  double get minExtent => 106;

  @override
  Widget build(
    BuildContext context,
    double shrinkOffset,
    bool overlapsContent,
  ) {
    double visiblePixels = max(minExtent, maxExtent - shrinkOffset);
    double travelledPixels = maxExtent - visiblePixels;
    double percentage = travelledPixels / (maxExtent - minExtent);

    return Material(
      color: Colors.white,
      elevation: percentage * 8,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        overflow: Overflow.clip,
                children: AppHorizontalScroll(
                    verticalPadding: 19,
                    horizontalPadding: 22,
                    betweenPadding: 13,
                    items: list,
                ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

So, here is the question.

In old iteration when I put print inside MyCustomWidget's build method, it printed every time persistent header was resized due to the scroll.

So to prevent that I put list of MyCustomWidget's in the variable, and now it's build method is called only one time.

Is that solution efficient, or is this a good practice?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty much simple: the less your build method gets called - the better.
So, if your new code does work the way you need, has reduced build() executions and it's not hard to extend when needed - you're good to go.
As for the List of Widgets - it's perfectly fine to use them like that too (and you can even make that variable "final" since you're not changing it anymore).
You can read more about Flutter performance optimization using this link: [Performance Best Practices](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/best-practices)

---

And a bit offtopic: If you want to make your code even cleaner, try using a linter in your project. I personally use [Pedantic by Dart Team](https://pub.dev/packages/pedantic).
For example: It will suggest to define that List variable as "final list = < PreferredSizeWidget>[]". Give it a try too.